# Share class with annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I want to use a simple class with hibernate annotations in a non db project.

I dont wanna dublicate the code and remove annotations.

Is there a way for doing this like using annotations in subclass for parent class's attributes. So i can share the parent class.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Edit:

For example: I have a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sample")
Class Sample{
    @Column(name = "attr1")
    private String attr1;
// getter setters etc.
}
```

This class works good for a java project with db dependencies set.
But I serve a restful service with this class.
My client app do not need any db related functions so I dont include any db related jars.
So this is my problem I want to use same classes since both are common for two projects. But I do not need db jars which leads to @Entity annotations to compile errors.

If there is some way to do this, I would be very happy.

Thanks alot.

Comment: What? If your project doesn't read those annotations, then there's no problem having them there.

Comment: I believe that this is a question of "how can I package my classes such that the packaged artifact does not require hibernate as a dependency?"

Comment: Yes, since the annotated classes import the annotations from 3rd party jar, I have problems using them at different projects.

Answer (score -1):

use hibernate validation groups

[Basic Validation Example](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/jsr_303_beans_validation_using)

create 2 validation groups and use one of them for db project and other for not db project